# How to eager loading when there are further conditions on association objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, eager-loading

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I have the following `has_many :through` association in order to "order articles in categories":

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_associations                                     # Association objects
  has_many :associated_categories, :through => :category_associations # Associated objects
end

class CategoryAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => 'category_id = #{category_id} AND creator_user_id = #{creator_user_id}'

  belongs_to :associated_article
  belongs_to :creator_user, :foreign_key => 'creator_user_id'
end
```

On retrieving `associated_categories` I would like to load `category_associations` objects created by a user (*note*: the creator user is identified by the `creator_user_id` column present in the `category_associations` database table) *because* I need to display `position` values (*note*: the `position` attribute, an `Integer`, is required by the [`act_as_list`](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) gem and it is a column present in the `category_associations` database table) "near" each article title.

Practically speaking, in my view I would like to make something like the following in a *proper* and *performant* way (*note*: It is assumed that each article in `@articles` is "category-associated" by a user - the user refers to the mentioned creator user of `category_associations`):

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= link_to(article.title, article_path(article)) %> (<%= # Display the article position in the given category %>)
<% end %>
```

Probably, I should "create" and "handle" a *custom data structure* (or, maybe, I should make some else...), but I do not how to proceed to accomplish what I am looking for.

---

At this time I am thinking that the eager loading is a good approach for my case because I could avoid the [N + 1 queries problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) since I have to state further conditions on association objects in order to:

- retrieve specific attribute values (in my case those refer to `position` values) of *association* objects created by a given user;
- "relate" (in some way, so that `position` values are suitable for displaing) each of those specific attribute values to the corresponding *associated* object.

Comment: default scope with an include?

Comment: @apneadiving - How you'd make that with a `scope` method? Can you post an example since my case (I think) is a contrived one?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for this

```
@articles = Article.includes(:associated_categories)
```

This will eager load all your articles including both of its associations (associated_categories, associated_categories). Thus, it will avoid N+1 problem and wont fire queries when you iterate over @articles and its associations in your view.

Comment: I am looking for retrieving and displaying `position` values for each article (assumed that each article is "category-associated" by a **given** user - the creator user of associations), *maybe* with eager loading (if eager loading is a "proper" and "performant" approach in my case).

Comment: @user12882: Where does position comes from? does that already exists or you want to dynamically create position number?

Comment: The `position` comes from `category_associations`: (as I wrote in the question) the `position` attribute, an `Integer`, is required by the `act_as_list` gem and it is a column present in the `category_associations` database table. Each associated category has one o more *ordered* category associations and more users can associate an article to multiple categories. I am looking for "retrieving" / "filtering" associated categories and related category associations where category associations are *created by a given user*.

Comment: @user12882: If position is coming from category_associations, you can access them using, @articles.each{|article| article.category_associations.each{|ca| p ca.position }}. As they are already eager loaded, extra queries wont be fired.